# Should the [good-design] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120768/how-to-implement-the-factory-pattern-in-c-correctly) has the [good-design](/questions/tagged/good-design) tag on it.  I considered changing it to [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices), but that tag does not exist.

Was the [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices) tag nuked recently, and if so, shouldn't [good-design](/questions/tagged/good-design) be similarly disposed?

Comment: Yes, it should be nuked. Especially since there's no `bad-design` tag...

Comment: OK, retagging this so The Team can see it, since it appears I have no way of doing this.  Developers developers developers developers...

Answer (score 3):

It was one of the first tags which was [nuked](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) around August last year.

Yes, in my opinion [good-design](/questions/tagged/good-design) is also a good candidate for this.